# Why is types megin broken when export is removed?

Tags: typescript

Why do types of `"koa-session"` get broken when I comment `export {}` in types.d.ts? 
Could you give me a link to the docs if such explanation exists? (couldn't find by myself)
[image]
[image]

Comment: When you ask a question, you have to use text and not screenshot. Please, update your question.

Comment: @SorcererApprentice the screenshots are pretty useful in this case. Text won't make you solve the problem if you don't know how to solve it

Comment: You are declaring and importing a module which doesn't have a session function and you're using the import as a function.

Comment: @ritaj Thanks! The problem is that when I uncomment "export {}" Session interface is merged with the rest types (from @types/koa-session), but when I comment it then everything is broken